# arm gcc assembly inline with FPU register

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, cortex-m, fpu

I want to use FPU instruction of Cortex-M7, called VCVTR, to convert a double precision floating number to an integer.

```
int double_to_int(double value)
{
    int result;
    __asm("VCVTR.S32.F64 %0, %1" : "=r"(result), "r"(value));
    return result;
}
```

But I get error information from the compiler.

> Error: VFP single, double or Neon quad precision register expected -- `vcvtr.s32.f64 r3,r3'

How to fix this problem.

Maybe the constraint "=r" and "r" is not correct. But I don't know other constraints for FPU registers.

My compiler is arm-none-eabi-gcc, version is 7.2.1

My compiler option is

> -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv5-d16 -O3 -g -munaligned-access

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) for extended assembly.  On [this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html) it tells you what constraints there are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters the compiler is perfectly capable of generating that instruction. Not only capable, but in fact a simple `return value` produces that. Nevertheless, the [constraints are documented in the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html). In particular:

> t VFP floating-point registers s0-s31. Used for 32 bit values.
>
> w VFP floating-point registers d0-d31 and the appropriate subset d0-d15 based on command line options. Used for 64 bit values only.

Also you accidentally specified two output constraints. `value` should of course be an input.

Comment: Why two output constraints. `value` has no "=". I try __asm("VCVTR.S32.F64 %0, %1" : "=t"(result) : "w"(value));, and the compiler show an error message : Error: operand size must match register width -- `vcvtr.s32.f64 s13,s14'.  It seems "w" constraint does not generate "d" register. It generates "s" register

Comment: Two outputs because the syntax is `outputs : inputs : clobbers` and you used a comma not a colon. Not sure why it generates `s` instead of `d` contrary to documentation. Anyway, what's wrong with letting the compiler emit the instruction?

Comment: By adding a load instruction, it seems work.     __asm("VLDR.F64 d0, %1\r\n"
          "VCVT.S32.F64 %0, d0"
          : "=t"(result)
          : "m"(value)
          : "d0"); Thank you :-)

Comment: You say "the compiler is perfectly capable of generating that instruction", but I think you missed the crucial difference between vcvt and vcvtr. It's trivial to get gcc to generate vcvt, but I don't think there's a way to get it to produce vcvtr?

Comment: That is true. However the original question, while certainly using the `R` version, did not specify the need for that particular rounding mode.