gcc thumb2 inline assembly for fixed point conversion
I would like to write some gcc inline assembly for armv7em on Cortex-M7 to perform conversion between floating point numbers and fixed point numbers. ARM provides the vcvt instruction with #fbits to achieve exactly this: ARM instruction documentation. I struggle to find the correct double precision implementation.
For a float implementation I came up with the following code:
float fractional_to_float(int32_t op1)
{
    float result;
    asm ("vmov.32 %0, %1\n\t"
         "vcvt.f32.s32 %0, %0, %2" :
         "=w"(result) :
         "r" (op1), "I" (FRACTIONAL_BITS) :
         /* no clobber */);
    return result;
}

int32_t float_to_fractional(float op1)
{
    int32_t result;
    asm ("vcvt.s32.f32 %1, %1, %2\n\t"
         "vmov.f32 %0, %1" :
         "=r"(result) :
         "w" (op1), "I" (FRACTIONAL_BITS) :
         /* no clobber */);
    return result;
}

What would the double precision implementation look like? I'm trying to come up with functions like:
double fractional_to_double(int32_t op1);
int32_t double_to_fractional(double op1);


You most likely do not need the vmov instructions.  Just constrain the source/destination operand to sit in the right type of register and let the compiler move it there.

Thank you for your replies.
The vmov instruction might be indeed unnecessary as you suggested @fuz but I struggle to write the inline assembler without it. For vcvt the source and destination register must be equal. So when I use different constrains the compiler tries to assign different registers, which the assembler will reject.
Cortex-M7 hast double precision hardware support. However '=w' only expands to single precision registers, not double precision registers. I'm not sure gcc supports a constrain for double precision registers.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51965500/arm-gcc-assembly-inline-with-fpu-register

A solution in the link above is to add VLDR.F64 d0, %1, to get a double.  You can also use the register double target asm ("d0"); and then set a clobber.  The documentation seems consistently wrong (which is strange...).

@artlessnoise: Set a clobber?  With register ... asm("regname") variables, you should use that variable as a register operand (input and/or output) to your asm statement, which will force the compiler to pick that register for the "r" or whatever constraint.  There are no guarantees beyond that, so just using a clobber on "d0" but still writing the register you used for a register-asm local variable can break, and probably will on clang.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html

@artlessnoise: Also, do you need to manually specify a register?  Can't you let the compiler pick with an appropriate constraint for a d register and just use %0 or %[name] in the asm template?

@PeterCordes 'clobber' was the wrong word.  Please note that the underlying issue is that the gcc specifier "w" does not select a 'dx' register (double precision) on ARM32 compiles.  It is documented like this and I looked at the source for alternates, but could not find one.  I posted an answer and deleted some of my comments.

@artlessnoise: Ok, I hoped you actually meant an operand rather than a clobber.  Thanks for posting an answer; interesting that a register-asm local var can get the compiler to pick a d register when it doesn't on its own.

As per this godbolt example, you can use a register variable to force use of a double register.
#include <stdlib.h>
#define FRACTIONAL_BITS 4
int test (double d)
{
    // get the compiler to use 64-bit d0 as an input
    //  even though "w" only picks a 32-bit s register
    register double target asm ("d0") = d;
    int result;

// First 2 operands must be the same register for fixed-point vcvt
    asm ("vcvt.s32.f64 d0, d0, #4   @ operand 0 picked %0\n" 
        : "=w"(result)
        : "0"(target), "I"(FRACTIONAL_BITS)
    );

    // "0" is a matching constraint: pick the same reg as the output %0
    // compiler picked s0 for result and target even with
    //    register int result asm("d0")
    // But it does emit a vmov.f64 d0, d1 to copy the whole 64-bit double 
    //  if it arrived in a reg other than d0

    return result;
}

This results in the assembler,
test:
 vcvt.s32.f64 d0, d0, #4   @ operand 0 picked s0
 vmov    r0, s0  @ int
 bx      lr

Options used are -mcpu=cortex-m7 -O3  -mfpu=fpv5-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard
Replacing the explicit d0 in the inline with %1 results in s0 use (with either 'target' or 'd').  Note that with an EABI, the float/double is passed in 'd0', so this is working for a function, but if you try to inline (macros, just asm, inline function), it may break or at least result in extraneous moves.
A specifier that works would be the best, but it appears that the documented "w" only selects float registers.  To work around this, a specific double register is selected and used in the inline assembler.  A specifier is better in that the compiler will give the in use register, which allows inlining. I use 'inlining' to mean a concept of no function call, which can be achieved in various ways.

Yes, I could file a bug, but so could you.  As well, I don't want to waste gcc dev time, in case I am wrong.  However, many sources are indicating that 'w' doesn't work for double values.

This shouldn't break when inlined, unless somehow GCC doesn't realize that d0 aliases s0 and s1.  But I think you have the asm operands wrong: vcvt needs both operands in FP registers, and you need a separate vmov to copy from FP to integer (which hopefully you can let the compiler do, if you tell it to pick an s register for the result).  https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0473/m/vfp-instructions/vcvt--between-floating-point-and-fixed-point-  And on Godbolt if you "compile to binary object" to ask it to assemble the asm, it's an error. https://godbolt.org/z/q8M6T1MYT

So I think you want asm ("vcvt.s32.f64 d0, d0, #4  \n" : "=w"(result) : "0"(target), "I"(FRACTIONAL_BITS)); - https://godbolt.org/z/e5TvK5Txz - with some testing with extra function args, GCC does seem to understand the input and output.  Fixed-point vcvt apparently requires both input and output use the same register, maybe because the encoding needs those bits for the precision instead of another reg number.

result = (int)target; is another conversion, not a type-pun (memcpy or std::bit_cast).  Or see my previous comment's godbolt link - an "=w"(int_var) output works, telling GCC the i32 bits are in the s register it picks, or tell GCC the output is a float and memcpy it to an int to get vmov r0, s0 without an extra vcvt.

Oh, yeah there's an edit mark, I think I did post that comment and then rewrite it after figuring out what was going on.  Anyway, the code in your answer currently doesn't assemble with GCC/GAS on Godbolt, but I think my version is correct and hopefully safe even when inlined.  https://godbolt.org/z/nPjenfTve is a tidied up version with testing/experiments removed.
